How to correlate records sent via `PUT /rows` with the error details from `GET /results`?
I'm trying to import product data into DataExtensions using the async API. Consider the example below:
PUT /data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:DEX_PRODUCT_API/rows
{
  "items": [
    {
      "ID": 1640,
      "CATEGORY": "GIFT",
      "SKU_NUMBER": "384455",
      "UPC": 1234567890123,
    }
  ]
}

The UPC field was created as Int32; therefore, this won't be imported, as the example value exceeds the datatype limit. However, I was expecting to see the ID field in the output of the results endpoint below, as it is the primary key for this DEX:
GET /data/v1/async/443ac6e1-01ca-41ca-bac5-50caada9d08a/results
{
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 1,
    "count": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "errorCode": 2,
            "errors": [
                {
                    "errorMessage": " Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.Couldn't store <1234567890123> in UPC Column.  Expected type is Int32.",
                    "name": "UPC",
                    "errorCode": 2
                }
            ],
            "message": "Errors Occurred",
            "status": "Error"
        }
    ],
    "requestId": "41a8b296-a63d-4cef-803c-f0370f0f4800",
    "resultMessages": []
}

Is there a way to correlate the records sent in the PUT /rows request with the error details received in the GET /results?

You can consider about changing UPC data type from Number to Text or Decimal https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_data_extension_data_types.htm&type=5

Thanks for the reply, @DucLe. We'll definitely do that, but our main issue here is connecting the error message with the failed record. You see, if the PUT request had more than one record, how can I tell which record failed?

I have tried to retrieve the result from the requestId and it seems if I have a failed record from upserting then it will be in order. Like if the 2nd record is failed then the retrieved results will show the 2nd element in items array with an error. Can use it to determine which ones were failed, I guess

Or if I have all product data, I would try to put them in a CSV file and manually import it into a Data Extension having same fields where UPC field is a Text field now. Hence I will compare the imported data extension with the existing one to exclude the identical rows (For example by SQL). The results are the failed ones
